# Sorting is not working with LIMIT while fetching results

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting, search

I am currently working on a website which is basically search based. End users can search the members that are currently registered on the website. The registered users can avail 3 membership packages Golden, Silver and Basic. I have a pagination in place and when I try to sort the result based on the package, I get duplication of results on different pages. For example, if I get a user on page 3, he may also appear on, say, page 6. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am pasting below my MySQL query that is fetching the result from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN prof_info 
ON users.id = prof_info.user_id 
WHERE (prof_info.work_country = 'Indonesia' 
       OR (prof_info.work_country ='' AND users.country = 'Indonesia'))
       AND users.firstname !=''
ORDER BY users.membership DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Membership packages have following database entry:

Golden=2, Silver=1, Basic=0. I want to be able to show Golden members in search result, than silver and afterwords basic members.

Code that creates pagination is

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $current_page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $current_page=1; };

$limit = 1; // number of results per page
$start_from = ($current_page-1) * $limit;
if(isset($total_results)){
$nav  = '';
$skip_links1 = 1;
$skip_links2 = 1;
for($page = 1; $page <= $total_pages; $page++)
{
   if ($page == $current_page)
   {
      $nav .= " $page "; // no need to create a link to current page

   }
   else
   {
       if(($page > 2) && ($page < $total_pages-2) && ($page > $current_page + 2)){//number of pages exceeding 5
       if($skip_links1 == 1)
        $nav .= " ... ";
        $skip_links1 =0;
       }elseif($page >2 && $page < $current_page -2 ){
           if($skip_links2 == 1)
           $nav .= " ... ";
           $skip_links2=0;
      }else{
          $nav .= "<a href='doctors.php?page=".$page."&country=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&speciality=".$_GET['speciality']."&name=".$_GET['name']."'>".$page."</a> ";
     }
  }
}

if ($current_page > 1)
{
   $page  = $current_page - 1;
   $prev  = " <a href='doctors.php?page=".$page."&country=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&speciality=".$_GET['speciality']."&name=".$_GET['name']."'><</a> ";

   $first = " <a href='doctors.php?page=1&country=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&speciality=".$_GET['speciality']."&name=".$_GET['name']."'><<</a> ";
}
else
{
   $prev  = '&nbsp;'; // we're on page one, don't print previous link
   $first = '&nbsp;'; // nor the first page link
}

if ($current_page < $total_pages)
{
   $page = $current_page + 1;
   $next = " <a href='doctors.php?page=".$page."&country=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&speciality=".$_GET['speciality']."&name=".$_GET['name']."'>></a> ";

   $last = " <a href='doctors.php?page=".$total_pages."&country=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&speciality=".$_GET['speciality']."&name=".$_GET['name']."'>>></a> ";
}
else
{
   $next = '&nbsp;'; // we're on the last page, don't print next link
   $last = '&nbsp;'; // nor the last page link
} ?>
<div id="tableNav">

<?php
echo "<center>".$first . $prev . $nav . $next . $last."</center>";

?>
</div>
<?php
        }//end of if(isset($total_results))
```

?>

Comment: Show code that creates pagination

Comment: is user, membership combination coming duplicate in the result set?   as per the current query, user might appear in gold package page1 and same user might appear in page 6 under basic pacakge.

Comment: Check for duplicate data in tables

Comment: I have also included the pagination code. It may help in determining the faulty area.

Comment: @radar. Some of the users are appearing on multiple pages. although they have only one entry in database and can either be a golden , silver or basic member at a time.

Comment: There are no dublicate entries in the database tables.

Comment: Have u tried running the query in mysql? and didn't find duplicates?

Comment: the query was working fine before adding "ORDER BY users.membership DESC " portion. No duplicate entries are fetched without this line of code

Comment: @DDphp.There are no duplicate entries in database and a user can only have one membership at a given time.

Comment: Use group by or order by on two columns....and try

Comment: can you please post the query? As i am new to mysql queries and still learning.

Comment: if i add the order by on another column, won't it stop sorting the result? as the only column which has membership details is users.membership.

Answer (score 0):

First of all swap `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` because you have **on clause**. 
Secondly, it seems like you have duplicates in your table. You can get only 1 membership type per user, for example highest one by using this query

```
SELECT 
    *,MAX(users.membership)
FROM
    users
       INNER JOIN
    prof_info ON users.id = prof_info.user_id
WHERE
    (prof_info.work_country = 'Indonesia'
        OR (prof_info.work_country = ''
        AND users.country = 'Indonesia'))
        AND users.firstname != ''
GROUP by users.id
ORDER BY users.membership DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```